# Why doesn't absolutely positioned element ignore it's sibling position, appearing after it?

Tags: css, css-position

`<a>` is positioned *relatively*, while `<span>` *is nested inside it and is positioned absolutely*. Yet, `<span>` appears below the **bottom** left corner of the image, instead of appearing at **top** left corner of it's relative parent. I can't understand **why does it not ignore** it's sibling's position.

Here is my code:

```
.pos-rel {
    position:relative;
}

.pos-abs {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px; 
    right:0px;
}

<a href="#" class="pos-rel">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/270x270" class="img-responsive">
    <span class="label label-primary pos-abs">Overlay</span>
</a>
```

Picture of an expected behavior:

[image]

It is most likely that I don't understand how `position:relative` and `position:absolute` work together in this case. Can anyone explain why the behavior illustrated on the picture is not taking place?

Comment: Strictly speaking, the absposed element should still ignore the in-flow sibling. But your picture does not match your code - for one, the absposed element is being anchored to the left, not the right.

Comment: @BoltClock I took the picture of that exact code. I guess something else is also happening, as I still can't fix the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to how the display of `<a>` is expressed in terms of CSS. Usually, it's `display: inline`. Absolute positioning [works quite differently](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#containing-block-details) when the `position: relative` ancestor is an inline element:

> The containing block of an element is defined as follows:
>
> 4. If the element has 'position: absolute', the containing block is established by the nearest ancestor with a 'position' of 'absolute', 'relative' or 'fixed', in the following way:
>
>    1. In the case that the ancestor is an inline element, the containing block is the bounding box around the padding boxes of the first and the last inline boxes generated for that element. In CSS 2.1, if the inline element is split across multiple lines, the containing block is undefined.

The inline box generated by the `<a>` (to contain the `<img>`) is the same height as the line box that it's in, and the height of the `<img>`, which itself is inline, is irrelevant. So the absposed element is placed at around the same height as the line box the `<img>` is sitting on. The `<img>` is positioned the way it is because it's sitting on the *baseline* of the `<a>`.

As you can imagine, setting the `<a>` to `display: block` produces the expected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

`<a>` is `inline`, you must change it to `block` and set width or `inline-block` to let it assume the width of it's contents.

Included the jsfiddle to reflect what you were aiming for: https://jsfiddle.net/gq30uct4/

Answer (score 0):

NEW ANSWER:

As @ISuthan Bala wrote, `<a>` is inline element, so you have to add your relative class to an additional DIV inside the `<a>` tag:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VaqmWN

```
.pos-rel {
    position:relative;
}

.pos-abs {
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px; 
    left:0px;
}

<a href="#">
  <div class="pos-rel">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/270x270" >
    <span class="label label-primary pos-abs">Overlay</span>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for a reply. The `position:relative;` works despite the `<span>` being an inline element. I've added `display:inline-block;` to it, but nothing changed.